# New Relic for rails production

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I tried to apply new relic to my rails application in Digitalocean vps. But it seemed not working. I waited in new relic and didn't see any data transfer through the new relic dashboard.

Here is my new_relic.yml
https://gist.github.com/phuong3030/8859addbb8d097ad6cd4

Thank for helping!

Answer (score 1):

It is puma and new relic problems. I fixed it by config puma restart in sub thread.